# Resize partition safely

Tags: 18.04, partitioning

I'd like to inscrease the size of partition 2 (21 Go) to 100 Go.
To free space I'll decrease the size of partion 4 (965 Go) to 886 Go.

If I do this with this tool  , is there a risk ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is always some risk, so you always have good backups. But it is not as simple as shinking one partition and expanding another. You would have to shrink your /home & move it right. The mode sda3, your ESP right and the you can expand sda2. But why increase sda2. I normally use 25GB for / (root) and current use 8GB of that. But I have all data in other partitions. Your / (root) should not need that much space.

Comment: I'm not so good in linux but I'm working on creating some websites and they are stored in /var/www/html/ , and day after day this partition become so busy. Have you an idea ? That's why I'd like to increase the size of this partition